# How can I create a list of files in a folder with adb, including time stamps?

Tags: adb, windows

I'm a new adb user and am trying to build some automation with images from my Android. I've been able to connect, 'ls' and push/pull files. What I want to do is determine the most recent file(s) in the Camera folder on the phone and pull that one. Is there a way to do this?

My command in Win 10 is "adb ls /path-to/Camera", which produces a list with some numbers preceding the filenames, e.g.

```
000081f9 005145e2 607f4c6e 20210420_144934.jpg
000081f9 004430cb 607f4c7c 20210420_144949.jpg
000081f9 0031701e 6080d67e 20210421_185054.jpg
000081f9 003847b0 6080e058 20210421_193256.jpg
```

If I add 'shell' to that ("adb shell ls /path-to/Camera") I just get the filenames, though they're in 3 columns:

```
20201121_144842_HDR.jpg 20210311_155639.jpg     20210421_185054.jpg
20201121_144902.jpg     20210312_225720.jpg     20210421_193256.jpg
20201121_144911.jpg     20210312_230021.jpg     20210422_065438.jpg
```

Can I save the list to an array or hash with timestamps? Or figure a way to determine the most recent files?

Thanks, Scott

Comment: Have you tried `adb shell ls -l /path-to/Camera`? `-l` means "long", ie. with details. Which parameters `ls` supports depends on how your device's busybox/toybox binary was compiled; full parameters for your use case would be `-latr` (Long, All files, sorted by Time Reverse (i.e. newest one first)).

Comment: The easiest way I know is to use find command. Search for how to find recently created files using find command. Use that with adb. If for some reason your Android's find binary doesn't support some arguments, use busybox's find or better, termux.